# Como activo el SQL Agent en SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero utilizar un job en mi base da datos, para eso necesito activar el Sql Agent

Trate de darle activacion desde mi panel de control pero aun no aparece para dar de alta mi job

Comment: Hola Paulina, te doy la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero completar [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. En tu caso intenta explicar mejor tu problema y que has intentado para conseguir solucionarlo hasta ahora.

Answer (score 4):

Puede deberse a una o a varias de las siguientes razones:

1. El usuario que estás utilizando no tiene privilegios para ver el Agente
2. Estás usando una versión express de SQL Server
3. Estás usando una versión express del Managment Studio

Cuando hablas de activación, es posible que te refieras a subir el servicio del agente... eso lo puedes hacer desde el SQL Server Configuration Manager o desde los Servicios del sistema operativo.